# python regex - escaping with raw string

Tags: python, regex

Using Python 3.6

```
f = './data/sample_input/path1_name/path2_name\\ABC_DEF_Succ.txt'
regex = r'\\\\(.*)\.txt'
matches = re.search(regex, f)
```

here `matches` is giving `None`. I tried with https://pythex.org/ and it is giving the expected match `ABC_DEF_Succ`. What is that I'm not doing right here ?

Comment: If you're using a raw string, you don't need to escape the backslashes: `re.search(r'\\(.*)\.txt', f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following user @ggorlen's suggestion, when using a raw string, don't need to escape the backslashes - that works !!

```
f = './data/sample_input/path1_name/path2_name\\ABC_DEF_Succ.txt'
regex = r'\\(.*)\.txt'
matches = re.search(regex, f)
matches.group(1) #=> 'ABC_DEF_Succ'
```